# How do I make text blink with blessed?

Tags: python-3.x, blessed

Im trying to make a blinking cursor for a Fallout 4 Termlink emulator
In order to make the menu system work, I need to have a flashing cursor to move around.
I saw that with a previous version of blessed (blessed 1.9) that there was an attribute called blink, but it appears that there isn't one now. For some reason I can't access the documentation as for some reason, when I hit the link, it takes me to a blank page that just says reset.

As stated above, I tried using the blink attribute, but was told that there was no such attribute in the currant version of the blessed library

`print(term.cursor.blink+'▓')`

> AttributeError: 'ParameterizingString' object has no attribute 'blink'

If I try `print(term.bold_blink_white_on_black"▓")` it prints out the character, but it doesn't blink or anything.